# Mac makes beeping sound every five minutes without pop up notification. Origin unknown

Tags: macos, audio

My Mac (Macbook pro 13 early 2011, running 10.13.6 (High Sierra) makes unknown sound exactly every five minutes. I already tried rebooting and PRAM reset. Didn't help.

The sound it makes:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vkuE5VEGzaZYtVF1X_V4tQh5ADb2W1qe

If anyone could help, I would extremely appreciate. Thank you very much.

console: (10:33:38)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue a long time ago. Turns out I had inadvertently turned on the beep every half hour feature in Date and Time preferences... DOH!

Comment: The logs show 3 minutes and some seconds _past_ the half-hour.

Comment: There is this feature that has your mac beep every 30 mins. Maybe you accidentally turned it on? It's in System Preferences -> Date and Time -> Clock -> Announce the Time

Comment: Thank you Steve Chambers and An Existing Person for a recommendation, however, unfortunately, this isn't the case. The option to announce the time is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for commenting.

Finally, I managed to identify the culprit. The sound (beeping) was actually an alert by the app (Effortless). (I quit app by app, when the sound suddenly stopped). The alert got probably turned on by a recent update, as I don't remember turning it on/off.

Here is the preference I needed to turn on to mute the sound.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One potential source of an elusive beep is Gmail on Chrome.

[image: Screenshot of the Desktop notifications in Gmail not Chrome]

If you run Gmail on Chrome, go to **Gmail Settings** (not Chrome Preferences), look at **General** > **Desktop Notifications**, and confirm whether the sound you hear is the one selected (and whether there is incoming mail at these times).